# Apply CSS to one page only and not all

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

In rails I have a CSS file in my `app/asset/stylesheet/x.css`.
I want to apply it only in a `show.html.erb` page in one controller.

That works correctly, but my CSS is also applied to all my app's pages.

How do I apply this CSS only on the `show` page? (I want a separate CSS file from my HTML).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the outermost element of the page an `id`, e.g. `<div id="show-page">` and then in your CSS use `#show-page` in the selector for each style you want to apply only to that page, e.g.:

```css
#show-page h1 {
  color: blue;
}

#show-page p {
  font-size: larger;
}

/* ...and so on... */
```